# extjs3 editor grid restrict enter key behavior

Tags: extjs, grid, key, extjs3

In ExtJS3 I am using editor grid. On click of enter the focus automatically moves to the next row and moves the field into editor mode.

Is there anyway i can change the behavior and restrict the focus to move to next row, instead on hitting enter stay on the same field and move out of edit mode.

Answer (score 0):

Configure the `keys` property of the editor grid.

According to the api

> keys : Object/Array
>
> A Ext.KeyMap config object (in the format expected by
>   Ext.KeyMap.addBinding used to assign custom key handling to this panel
>   (defaults to null).

KeyMap is configured like so

```
var map = new Ext.KeyMap("editor-grid-id", {
    key: 13, // or Ext.EventObject.ENTER
    fn: myHandler, //return false to cancel the event, or whatever you want to do in the method
    scope: myObject  //the 'this' variable that you would like to use inside the myHandler method
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a RowSelectionModel, you can set `moveEditorOnEnter` to `false` in its config object.

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.grid.RowSelectionModel-cfg-moveEditorOnEnter